# How to configure the "Share Working Copy" option in Xcode 5?

Tags: xcode5

I have code files for an app in two different repositories (let's say "App" and "Library"), both under source control. 
When I drag&drop the "Library" files into the Xcode Project, Xcode asks me if I want to "Share Working Copy". 
I first selected "No", but now I would like to opt-in to this option. However I cannot find an option to do so.

What I tried:
* removing the "Library" files and adding again
* same as above, but also quitting and reopening Xcode during the process

However the "Share Working Copy?" dialog never showed up again. Is there a configuration somewhere?